# Could this trap be siphoning?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, p-trap

I've attached a picture of the trap for my washer. The closet that this is in smells like septic tank gas so I assume it is leaking out of the standpipe. I haven't seen this type of trap before and I'm wondering if perhaps the unusual trap design is to blame.  From the top of the elbow in the top of the picture the standpipe rises 22". from the top of the exit of the trap is 28". The vent does connect through the ceiling to the main part of the vent stack.

[image: [1]]
stand pipe is on the left. vent on the right

[image: 1]]

close up view of vent stack
[image: 2]]

Comment: The third picture shows you have a leak, and the smell is coming from the leak,  The leak is dripping down to the wash room. The leak from above is dripping down and spattering on to the P-trap.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the overflow or whatever is on the sill plate would be more likely to cause a problem it looks like you have enough area for a trap but the angle could be deceiving. If there is enough water to trap the gas the next thing to look at that may be pulling water out of a trap is a plugged vent. I have seen plugged vents pull water out of several traps when a toilet was flushed.

Added per op photo: 
Ok wow the leak looks to be from a no hub or fernco coupler. That may be the source of the smell, in a case like this I like to run some bleach water prior to working on it even in my own home. 2 reason it flushes nastys down ant if you can smell the bleach the fernco is leaking. 
If this is leaking it would be best to purchase a new one I like the metal reenforced like you have they keep the rubber from bulging. 
These are a rubber sleeve with pipe clamps at top and bottom, the plastic pipe on top and cast below both fit and this is the seal. 
Tips use a wire brush on the cast to clean it up. Wipe down the plastic pipe. 
I put a coating of silicone calking in a few of the ribs inside the rubber this helps to seal especially on the rusty cast not a lot barely fill 2-3 ribs or a light film if no ribs.
Get it in place and tighten the hose clamps. , I don’t think your trap is bad but when a toilet flushes if your vent above is not clear it may pull the water out but the design looks ok.

Comment: I've updated my question with a few more pictures that should help with the angle and a close-up of the vent stack.

Comment: Hmm, it might be, If it does need a new fernco, the pvc is 1.5", but has some type of nut looking thing on it (size change?), and the cast iron is 2.5" OD. Would I get a 2" fernco or 1.5 to 2"? Thanks!

Comment: I would double check the size on that adapter fernco can handle some size difference like cast / pvc And there are special ones to change sizes but I would guess they should be the same double check as the ones that change sizes may be harder to find.

Comment: You might be best served by taking that Fernco off and taking it to the store. If you go to a plumbing supply house instead of a big-box, you'll significantly increase your odds of A) finding the exact part you need, and B) getting some _expert_ advice* since they can see it in person. Sometimes you'll get a former plumber working in the plumbing aisle of the big-box, sometimes you'll get a college kid looking to make some cash over the summer... *no offense to Ed, but he's guessing on the size based on a pic - he'd do just fine if he saw it in person, too.